# A bug in the views calculation. Views: 0 time

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, views

I look today on a few fresh question, and the view count was 0. Even after I refreshed the page a few time. This is definitely a bug, since the question isn't mine.

Also I don't think the all page was cached, since that the DateTime mark was change every reload.

But maybe the SQL result is cached.

Comment: At least the pluralization is correct. It says "0 times", rather than "0 time".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We buffer view count increments, so this should be normal -- unless the post stays at 0 for more than say 5 minutes or so.

You didn't provide any links to questions so I can't verify this is the case, but we haven't had any other reports of this.

Comment: @Jeff Could you make a list of all the parts of StackOverflow that are cached?

Comment: @cha this is not caching, this is buffered writes.

Comment: Make this FAQ; I've seen questions like this a few times

Comment: @Jeff I cannot provide any links because after a few seconds the views was 2. but in this few seconds I refreshed the page a few times and it was 0 view.

Comment: @Jeff What do you mean 'We *buffer*...'? Is this a kind of cache?

Comment: I've also seen this at least once since I even thought about posting this on meta. Situation got 'corrected' quite fast.

Comment: Shouldn't the number of "Views" start at "1" ?

Comment: @ldigas no. when a post was created and no one has been sew it, the view need to be 0. but as soon as you sew it, the view need to be one. or at least at the nest time you refresh the page.

Comment: @Mendy: Sew it? Is there a threading issue?