# Idea behind profile view count?

Tags: support, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dissecting the Stack Overflow views counter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87092/dissecting-the-stack-overflow-views-counter)
>   [How are profile views counted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132688/how-are-profile-views-counted)

> My question is in relation with this question:
>   [How are profile views counted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132688/how-are-profile-views-counted)

I want to know how SO is measuring the **profile view count**?

Is it based on

1. unique IPs accessed the page OR
2. unique Users accessed the page OR
3. some time interval set in between the views from a same IP or user

**And if I am watching someone's profile everyday, will that add up to their profile view count?**

Comment: Sorry, but your question is thus a dupe of [How are profile views counted?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132688) You could offer a bounty on that question if the answer isn't to your satisfaction.

Comment: Also, the answer that *is* there does state that only *new* users are counted. Thus, if you watch someone's profile every day, those won't count as different.

Comment: see a link.http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87092/dissecting-the-stack-overflow-views-counter

Answer (score 6):

As far as my knoledge goes, the "profile views" counter, is intended to give you a "feedback" on the amount of unique users that have visited your profile.

**Having performed some tests at the office:**

- My own visits do not count at any time
- Visits from others count once when visiting on short periods of time (5min) **<sup>1</sup>**
- Visits from others count once when visiting on large periods of time (next day) **<sup>1</sup>**

**<sup>1</sup>** Visits only count if unique, doesn't increase the counter if it is the same user. To test the day after, was necessary to involve two co-workers.

---

About the "backstage" process, as mentioned on other related questions, only [developers](https://stackexchange.com/about/team) can clarify that.

Comment: Is there a reason behind the down-vote, that the down-voter may wish to clarify, to allow the answer improvement/removal? Or did down-votes became a like/don't like tool?