# How often is profile views updated?

Tags: support, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are profile views counted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132688/how-are-profile-views-counted)

The profile views in my profile displays the same number for a few hours. Then, the next time I look, it jumps by a few units. How often is this information updated in my profile?

Answer (score 0):

I think its updated regularly. Its not a number of times we have seen our profile. Its the number which shows how many users have seen our profile. So its possible that no one had seen your profile for hours. And then 5-6 users visited it when you were inactive. So you will find it jumped by few units.