# One vote after 10 minutes of posting. Still 1 view

Tags: bug, voting, views

Is there anything wrong with this? I have refreshed many time but the view still be 1.

[How to wake up before ejaculating in a wet dream?](http://sexuality.stackexchange.com/q/89/147)

[image: image description]

I don't think think this is a dup of [A bug in the views calculation. Views: 0 time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43751/260800). In that question. Jeff Atwood answers:

> We buffer view count increments, so this should be normal -- **unless the post stays at 0 for more than say 5 minutes or so**.

I submitted the question at 04:**33**:40Z, and got the first upvote at 04:**43**:13Z (I don't know what *Z* means).

Comment: @NormalHuman but in the question you linked, it says that every 5 minutes the system will update the number again (right?), while in fact I got the upvote after 10 minutes of posting.