# View count and vote count are not matching on a question

Tags: support, specific-question, up-votes, views

The screenshots speak for itself. How is it possible to have 2 upvotes but only 1 view (which should be anyway *my* view)?

[image]
[image]
[image]

[Link to the question](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/631/how-to-repair-a-mug). I tried to refresh and hard refresh but the view count is still stuck at 1.

I don't think that this is a cache problem (although I have to say that I know really little on the subject) because this never happened to me on other SE sites before. Moreover, I observe the same as the screenshots on 3 different browsers and after closing/reopening the browsers.

Comment: View count is one specific thing that is mentioned in the dup.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Well, I'm not sure it is because of the cache (although I have to say that I know really little on the subject) because this never happened to me on other SE sites before. Moreover, I observe the same on 3 different browsers.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I added the screenshot with 1 upvote to show why I was puzzled and replaced the *bug* tag by the *support* tag.

Comment: [status-bydesign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43751/a-bug-in-the-views-calculation-views-0-time)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure this is a caching 'problem'. The server side cache caches data sets specific to a view, so it is possible that the question page cache has another number as the main question list.

You just need to wait a few minutes, and all numbers will align again. You can't affect this yourself, so clearing your client side cache, using another browser, etc. doesn't help.

Comment: "You just need to wait a few minutes" I waited about 50 minutes between the first upvote and second one.

Comment: The question now has 4 views.

Comment: Indeed... So I guess this is not happening on math.SE because it's not a beta site..?

Comment: Not sure, but the cycles might not be that frequent on beta sites for example due to their lower traffic.

Comment: (we apparently came to the same point)